# Google App Engine (PHP) Response too large

Tags: php, google-app-engine

When using the get_headers() php function in a *deployed* app, e.g.:

```
$aHeaders = get_headers("http://[...].mp3", 1);
echo $aHeaders['Content-Length'];
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  get_headers(http://[...].mp3): failed to open stream:
>   Response too large in /base/data/home/apps/[...]/main.php

The error doesn't appear when the file is small (e.g. 100kb).

I need to get the size of a file on an external server without having to download it. Also, I can't use curl as it is not supported by GAE. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you try to do an HEAD request instead of a GET (that downloads all content)?

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);
$headers = get_headers('http://[...].mp3', 1);
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the "Response too large" warning comes from GAE's 32mb limit to HTTP requests.